# Tabular data import wizard control

Tags: .net, excel, controls

Are there any existing .NET (WPF-compatible) controls that generate a dialog similar to the Excel Flat-File-Import dialog?

What I am looking for specifically is an interface that shows the available columns of a chosen data source (XLS or CSV for starters) and allows the user to choose what type each column represents.
[image: Excel Column Chooser]

I know that it will require a significant amount of work to adjust it to my program, but it would be nice not to have to start from scratch.